# In a bipartite graph with 2 matchings saturating a subset of both sides, find a matching that saturates both subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

We are given a bipartite graph $G$ with parts $X,Y$; and also two matchings $M,M'$ such that $M$ saturates $S\subset X$, and $M'$ saturates $T\subset Y$. I need to prove the existence of a matching that saturates both $S,T$.

I tried to start from the matching $M$ by removing any edges in $M$ that do not saturate a vertex in $S$, and then include any edge $e_i\in M'$ that saturates some $v_i\in T$ that is not yet saturated. But if I do add such an edge, it might be joined to a vertex $v_i\in S$ that is already saturated. I would then have to remove the current edge saturating it, and so on. I don't know how to explain rigorously why this method will work (or maybe it won't and I am approaching it wrong).

Anybody know how to do this more rigorously?

Comment: Define saturates.

Comment: A vertex $v_i$ is saturated by a matching $M$ if the matching contains an edge $e_j$ that is attached to the vertex $v_i$. Hence $S$ being saturated by $M$ means that every vertex in $S$ has an edge attached to it that is in the matching $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\overrightarrow{M}$ be the edges of $M$ oriented from $X$ to $Y$ and let $\overrightarrow{M'}$ be the set of edges in $M'$ oriented from $Y$ to $X$. Any cycles in $\overrightarrow{M} \cup \overrightarrow{M'}$ can be "canceled" by removing the edges contributed by, say, $\overrightarrow{M}$, leaving an oriented forest $F$ in which every vertex in $S$ and $T$ have out-degree $1$. The out-degree of vertices in $S$ and $T$ implies that maximal paths end in neither $S$ nor $T$. Thus, we may also "cancel" maximal paths (of length at least 2) by keeping just those edges in the path that came from $\overrightarrow{M}$ if the path starts in $S$, or just those edges in $\overrightarrow{M'}$ if the path starts in $T$.

After canceling all maximal paths of length at least two, only independent arcs remain, and every vertex in $S \cup T$ is incident to an arc; the underlying edges form the desired matching.